# Was there historical influence of lattice theory on category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I know that Maclane and Eilenberg created category theory together. And I also know that lattice theory is a concept created by Dedekind with the motivation of ring and ideal theory. And this concept was developed by Ore and  Birkhoff. However, when I studied lattice theory, I saw that it started from the isomorphism of sets and then gradually expanded to topology space. So, I wonder if lattice theory may have influenced the emergence of category theory?

This is what I mean by "lattice" in this question.

> A lattice is an algebraic structure ${\displaystyle (L,\vee ,\wedge )}$, consisting of a set ${\displaystyle L}$ and two binary, commutative and associative operations ${\displaystyle \vee }$ and ${\displaystyle \wedge }$ on ${\displaystyle L}$ satisfying the following axiomatic identities for all elements ${\displaystyle a,b\in L}$ (sometimes called absorption laws):
> ${\displaystyle a\vee (a\wedge b)=a}$ ,
> ${\displaystyle a\wedge (a\vee b)=a}$
> The following two identities are also usually regarded as axioms, even though they follow from the two absorption laws taken together. These are called idempotent laws.
> ${\displaystyle a\vee a=a}$
> ${\displaystyle a\wedge a=a}$
> These axioms assert that both ${\displaystyle (L,\vee )}$ and
> ${\displaystyle (L,\wedge )}$ are semilattices. The absorption laws, the only axioms above in which both meet and join appear, distinguish a lattice from an arbitrary pair of semilattice structures and assure that the two semilattices interact appropriately. In particular, each semilattice is the dual of the other. The absorption laws can be viewed as a requirement that the meet and join semilattices define the same partial order.

Comment: See the top answer in [Was lattice theory central to mid-20th century mathematics? on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/150544/51484) and references there:"McLane worked around 1930-35 in matroid lattices and semimodularity (exchange axioms); when he invented categories, his interest in lattices had waned out, and he considered lattice theory a too specialized subject with too specialized questions. [More on the opposition categories / lattices below]."

Comment: Another good source is Corry's book [Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-7917-0) that describes the historical transition from early "structuralism", including Ore's lattice-based approach, to categories.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you so much for your answer. I was able to learn more about category theory and its relationship to lattice theory.

Comment: @user1274233 you may also be interested in: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-48272-4_12